# Why the generated id and name of an input are different, in a liftscreen

Tags: html, scala, lift

In a screen class which extends LiftScreen, I defined a text field:

```
class MyScreen extends LiftScreen {
  val stuffName = text("Stuff Name", "", trim, valMinLen(2, "2 chars at least"), 
      "class" -> "input-xlarge")
}
```

It generates the html as following:

```
<input style="float:left; margin-right: 10px" id="F666221395073GHLIXL" value="" 
    class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="F666221395059FXOCFK">
```

You can see the `id` and `name` attributes, have different generated values. What are the two attribute values used for? Why they are different? I thought they should be the same.

---

**Update**

Lift will use these generated values to match a function it stores on the server-side and run it.

For a single input, one unique value is enough for this, maybe `id`, maybe `name`, but why there are two different values?

If one of them are useless, lift doesn't need to generate it at all.

Comment: It's more a front-end/html related question, then Scala/Lift

Comment: I think it's a lift question. Lift generates them and uses them.

Comment: Well ids and names are supposed to be unique for each html element, maybe it's because of that?

Comment: @Dunno names do not need to be unique. consider radio buttons (or look at my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML forms, `id` and `name` are not the used for the same things. XML requires that each `id` is unique. This is not the case for `name`. Consider the following form:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="option" id="option1" />
  <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="option" id="option2" />
  <label for="option1">Option 2</label>
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="option" id="option3" />
  <label for="option1">Option 3</label>
</form>
```

The `name` of the three `input` tags must be the same to achieve the desired selection behavior (one out of the three). However, the `id` field needs to be unique (by specification and for the `label` tags).

Lift obviously aims to generate HTML that can support such a use case and hence has to generate `id` and `name` separately in this case. What you see is probably just a result of generalization (nothing *requires* `name` and `id` to be equal after all).